# Query Paragraph Type in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-entities

I am trying to Query all paragraphs of a certain type but I am not getting any output. Is my query right? Currently being returned an empty array.

```
$query = $this->node->getQuery()
          ->condition('type', 'my_paragraph_type')
          ->execute();
        $this->logger->info('query: ' . json_encode($query));
```

Comment: Can you also explain what instance of class does $this represents? And I am just being curious, where did you get this code? :)

Comment: sorry for hijacking this post for a sec - @j-e - deleting your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55482713/5221944)  after you got answer is not good practice here on SO. if you will reconsider your decision on this and undelete it - I will have chance to explain you why my answer helped you

Answer (score 3):

Try with entityQuery('entity_type')

```
$pids = \Drupal::entityQuery('paragraph')
  ->condition('type', 'my_paragraph_type')
  ->execute();
```